# How to write Junit for if else condition under thrown exceptions from rest template

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit4, resttemplate

I am new in Junit. I read basics of Mockito. I am not able to figure out how to write Junit for test code coverage.
I am using rest template calls to receive response object for requests sent.
I am executing some logic under  exceptions thrown (HttpStatusCodeException) here.
Below is my code:

```
public void processData(Request data, HttpHeaders headers, String priority) throws JsonProcessingException {

    try {

        HttpEntity<Request> reqEntity = new HttpEntity<>(data, headers);
        ResponseEntity<Response> helloResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(someendpoint, reqEntity, Response.class);
        if (priority.equals("low")) {
            func1();
        } else {
            func2();
        }

    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {

        if (ex.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) && priority.equals("low")) {

            func3();

        } else if (ex.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE) && priority.equals("high")) {

            func4();

        }

        else if (ex.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) && priority.equals("low")) {

            func5();

        }

        else if (ex.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN) && priority.equals("high")) {

            func6();

        }

        else {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Response response = mapper.readValue(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), Response.class);
            if (priority.equals("low")) {
                func7();
            } else {
                func8();
            }
            
        }

    }
}
```

}

It would be really helpful to get some help.

Answer (score 2):

do as below.

```
@Test
public void test1(){

Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any, ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Response>>any())).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(new Response(), HttpStatus.ok));
  //do your call and assertion
  //processData( data,  headers,  priority)
}
```

Testing for exception cover

```
  @Test
    public void testException1(){
    
    doThrow(HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).when(restTemplate).postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any, ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Response>>any());
    //do your call and assertion
    //processData( data,  headers,  "low")
    }
    
    
    
    @Test
    public void testException2(){
         doThrow(HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).when(restTemplate).postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any, ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Response>>any());
    //do your call and assertion
    //processData( data,  headers,  "low")
    }

  

   

 @Test
 public void testException3(){ 
         doThrow(HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).when(restTemplate).postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any, ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Response>>any());
            //do your call and assertion
            //processData( data,  headers,  "high")
            }
            
            
            
 @Test
 public void testException4(){
            
            doThrow(HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).when(restTemplate).postForEntity(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any, ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Response>>any());
            //do your call and assertion
            //processData( data,  headers,  "high")
            }
```

Comment: Did you got the solution from above.

Comment: For example testException2(), you can test like pass priority as low and create another test method as testException2() and pass priority as high like wise we can cover

Comment: I understand that it will break to two different testcases again. Do i need to chain to existing throw class for passing priority? If you can include it in answer it would be really great.

Comment: check now above

Comment: Mmm but if use see my function calls there has no arg. My general concern is can't we combine two when conditions like and(&&) case?

Comment: can  not do like that

Comment: Thanks i guess ,i need to reframe my code for writing tests.

Comment: welcome If answers fine then could you accect.